# OpenWebmail displays incorrect date in inbox

Tags: linux, email

OpenWebmail has been installed and configured well before I came on to my project.  I don't know how long this has been happening, but I'm starting to see that the dates are being displayed incorrectly on the inbox list.  Instead of MM/DD/YYYY, I am seeing MM/MM/YYYY.  I've checked the openwebmail.conf and default/openwebmail.conf files, but don't see anything that jumps out at me as being incorrect.  Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

date display is controlled on a per-user basis. Check in the user preferences for the `Display Preference -> Date format` pulldown.

Ask future questions about `OpenWebMail` on the mailing lists at:

http://openwebmail.acatysmoof.com/archive